# Efficient Pattern Matching for VERY LARGE File Directory

Tags: python, directory, glob

I need to get the paths of all JSON files in a file directory containing multiple million files and tens of thousands of folders in an efficient manner. I have tried the glob package in python, but after 20 minutes of waiting, I am looking for another avenue.

`glob.glob(directory + "\\**\\*.json", recursive=True)`

Comment: you could use the `mlocate` package on linux (an apt package)and just call it from python ... or use linux find or just ls maybe ... but i suspect `find` or `ls` will take just as long as python

Comment: _multiple terabyte file directory_ The total file size doesn't really matter.  How **many** files are there?

Comment: Since you tagged this as HPC I assume your code runs on a cluster file system such as lustre. Which one specifically? In general, those are notoriously bad at dealing with many small files. `glob` already uses [`getdents`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) which is the fastest option. So you are limited by what the operating system delivers. Try packaging your jsons into larger collections in zip files, [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dbm.html) or something like that

Comment: @JohnGordon, there are multiple million files and tens of thousands of folders.

Comment: @Homer512, the search is meant to be generalizable to any file directory, so packaging the jsons are unfortunately not an option.

Comment: What's your file system?

Answer (score 0):

The `glob` package includes the `glob.iglob` function, which behaves very similar to `glob.glob` but returns an iterable instead of a list.

This means that the program will not wait to traverse all your folder structure to return the whole list of matching files, but instead will make available to you one by one the matches as soon as they appear.

This also has the nice side effect of not letting the list of results fill your whole RAM. On the other hand though, not having all the results available at once can limit your options on latter processing, but it all depends on your use case.